# What is meant by mount point does not exist?

Tags: centos

I have a few servers which i need to mount a windows server directory to it

I using the following command:

```
# mount -t cifs //ntserver/download -o username=vivek,password=myPassword /mnt/ntserver
```

There are no issue with most servers.

However I encounter the following error with two particular server

```
mount error: mount point /mnt/ntserver does not exist
```

Anyone know the reason and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 17):

The directory `/mnt/ntserver` needs to exist on the machine before you can mount anything to it.

Answer (score 7):

In Unix and its variants, such as Linux, file systems are not made available by giving them unique drive letters like in Windows; instead, there is a single directory tree, and filesystems are made available by `mount`ing them somewhere within that tree.

One of the filesystems will serve as the basis for everything else (`/`) and everything else is mounted somewhere below in a subdirectory.  The directory where a filesystem is mounted must already exist, or the `mount` command will fail - if you ask me, it would be more logical and useful to require that it does *not* exist, but that's the way it is.